# What's the most secure way to ensure one account per user in a cross-platform mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, security, web, account

I'm working on a polling system, and I want to prevent people from making multiple accounts or generating accounts with a bot. It will have clients on iOS, Android, and web. How can I best protect the integrity of the polling data?

Comment: The eternal question. You'd have to rely on some other service that's difficult to create multiple accounts on. Phone verification is probably the most reasonable approach. Or you could go the Korean route and force your customers to give their SIN; but I can't see that being feasible.

Comment: Just add verification and maybe if you want to go for IP-based accounts. You can't 100% protect of course, but that will prevent 99.9% of all users to create multiple accounts..

Comment: Usually a fingerprint, retinal (iris) scan, or dna sample is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Phone verification such as SMS or a voice callback should be reasonably protective.

Comment: Please note that if the user can not access the app without phone verification, your app will get rejected.

Comment: How do you prevent people from using those temporary number services to verify?